# Create exception if the total sum is greater

Tags: java, android, sql

I'm trying to make an exception, but I do not know how to do it.
If the sum of the values in the records is greater than the total of 100000 do not do.

```
buttonPurchase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            ShoppingDAO shoppingDAO = new CompraDAO(getApplicationContext());

                            String amount = textTotal.getText().toString();
                            carros.setAmount(amount);
                            carros.setId_car(id);

                            SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("DB_SHOPPING", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM shopping where id_car="+id, null);

                            Cursor c2 = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(price * amount) FROM shopping;", null);

                            if(c.getCount()>0) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This purchase was made.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else {
                                if (c2.equals(100000)) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have reached the maximum amount of purchases.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                } else {
                                    if (compraDAO.salvar(carros)) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Purchase saved successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error saving.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            c.close();
                        }

                    });
```

Comment: `if (c2.getCount > 100000) throw new MyException();`

Comment: I tried to do this. But I can still buy.

Comment: Your problem is probably sql related then.

Comment: update your if statement `if(c.getCount()>0 && c2.intValue() < 100000)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you just have to update your if/else logic.

```
if(c.getCount()>0 && c2.intValue() < 100000){
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This purchase was made.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
   if(c2.intValue() >= 100000){
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have reached the maximum amount of purchases.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   } 
   ...
   ...
}
```

Comment: But I need to get on the table the sum of the records

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I learned that creating custom exceptions is not a good practice, because if you know the exception, you should prevent it instead, but, the others answered ways to do it, so you can do it.

Comment: I agree, what I’m saying is that if it’s conditionthat has high properly of causing an exception, you should design it to avoid calling the exception. As written here: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions